# Problem when put a element in array, using detach and append to another element using jquery click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, click, detach

Having a problem , can't explain because not sure what is happening. Just can only simplify the problem in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/7ZBtZ/1/)

**What hapening**

I'm putting the element in a array temporally, then when I put again doesn't have the **click** event.

**How to test**

1. Use "click me" button, will show the alert
2. detach, will change place
3. will appear the button "click me" in another place
4. click on the "click me" button , doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass true to `clone` method in order to preserve the events.

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/7ZBtZ/2/

Comment: You're solution it's very nice for the question. But next time have to read API documentation before. My main problem was deep copy needed to ue clone(true,true). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[@Shankar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000915/problem-when-put-a-element-in-array-using-detach-and-append-to-another-element-u/7000993#7000993) is fundamentally correct (+1), but there is a better way to do this. Right now, you:

1. Clone the element, then
2. Remove it, then
3. Detach it (which is redundant since the element was just removed), then
4. Append it

Instead, you can just [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach) the element, which

> is the same as [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove), except that `.detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

It would work something like this:

```
var $div = $('#div').detach();
hidden.push($div);
$('#click').remove();
hidden.pop().detach().appendTo('#div1');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/swBfj/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Shankar Sangoli found it first.